# How to make keyboard configuration as close as possible to Visual Studio or Eclipse in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

The biggest challenge  for me developing iphone and ipad application is the mac way of setup keyboard...

I'm in love for the ( ctrl + shift + arrows ) (home and end keys) (ctrl + key up or down) (shift + home or end) (page up and page down) when I am developing

I've searching a way to at least setup xcode to contain some or all those amazing key combinations we all like but I didn't find a good one

anybody had the same experience? could anybody give some directions?

thanks..

Comment: How to make Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts as close as possible to Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say it but this is your best bet...

In Xcode's preferences you can manually change the key bindings as you please.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can [remap](http://evansweb.info/2005/03/24/mac-os-x-and-home-end-keys) the home and end keybindings for the whole system.

edit or create the file:

```
~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

and add the following lines to it:

```
/* Remap Home / End to be correct :-) */
"\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";                   /* Home         */
"\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";                         /* End          */
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Home */
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";       /* Shift + End  */
```

You probably need to restart your computer as well.

I did this. But remember you will loose your mind getting to the end of the document if you sit at someone else's computer.
(note: eclipse seem to use its own bindings so it wont work there)